# Error testing sql query using mockito in java

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, easymock

I want to test the next function in java using EasyMock, Mock or Mockito.
I want to test that when I call to leerCantPueblos() function, the query("SELECT conarpueblos()") is executed.

```
private void leerCantPueblos(){
        cantPueblosBD = leerBD.cantidadPueblos();
        try {
            while(cantPueblosBD.next()){
                CANTIDADPUEBLOS = cantPueblosBD.getInt("contarpueblos");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

this function call to cantidadPueblos(), that is the next function.

```
public ResultSet cantidadPueblos() {
        try {
            sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
            ResultSet cantidadPueblos = sentencia.executeQuery("SELECT contarpueblos()");
            return cantidadPueblos;
        } catch (SQLException e) {}

        return null;
    }
```

I try with the next JUnit test but throws nullpointerexception

```
package tests;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.easymock.Mock;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import server.ConexionBD;

public class TestBD { 

    @InjectMocks
        ConexionBD conexionDB;

        @Mock
        Connection conexion;

        @Mock
        Statement sentencia;

        @Before
        public void setup() throws SQLException {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            //Mockito.initMocks(this);
            Mockito.when(conexion.createStatement()).thenReturn(sentencia);
        }

        @Test
        public void cantidadPueblos_shouldExecuteQuery() throws SQLException {
            conexionDB.cantidadPueblos();

            Mockito.verify(sentencia).executeQuery("SELECT contarpueblos()");
        }
}
```

The next row fail:

```
Mockito.when(conexion.createStatement()).thenReturn(sentencia);
```

Comment: sentencia is returned when createStatement is called on conexion but sentencia is never initialized. It is null!

Comment: And how can I initialized?sentencia = null? or I have to create the statement first? I am new to JUnit and mocking.. @RahulSharma

Comment: Could you add full code of the test? i.e. class declaration, imports

Comment: I have update the information with all the class code @Evgeny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test looks good except of the first line of `setup` method.

```
public void setup() throws SQLException {
    sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    //Mockito.initMocks(this);
    Mockito.when(conexion.createStatement()).thenReturn(sentencia);
}
```

It throws NPE as `conexion.createStatement()` is invoked before mocks are initialized. Just remove `sentencia = conexion.createStatement();` line, it is redundant here.

---

**UPDATE**

It turned out that wrong import is used. `import org.easymock.Mock` should be replaced by `import org.mockito.Mock;`

Comment: I get null pointer exception here: Mockito.when(conexion.createStatement()).thenReturn(sentencia); if I remove sentencia = conexion.createStatement(). I get null pointer exception to. @evgeny

Comment: @Asier It is impossible that `sentencia = conexion.createStatement();` didn't cause NPE and `Mockito.when(conexion.createStatement()).thenReturn(sentencia);` caused it. Did you provide final test version in the question?

Comment: I put now the final version, and when I execute it throws java.lang.NullpointerException and under this, it is at TestBD.setup(TestBD.java:31), and the line 31 is Mockito.when... @evgeny

Comment: @Asier NPE there means that mockito hasn't initialized `conexion` and that is strange. Do you use some custom test runner, i.e. `@RunWith` annotation?

Comment: I don't use nothing more, the class test is the same as I put here. I don't know what is the problem. @evgeny